# How to download images via directory browsing (No server access) All the images are indexed and can be accessed via url

Tags: html, apache, browser

For example:

When I go to site.com/images I get

Index of /images

- Parent Directory
- a-img.png
- app-bg.png
- arrow-left.png
- and so on....

Is there any script or something that I can use to download all these images at once? I don't have server access. Site is just html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do in this case is use [HTTrack](http://www.httrack.com/page/2/) and point it at the directory.

If will download all files that are linked to such as images and html and put it into a folder.

Then you can just delete the HTML, CSS and JS stuff and there you go!

Hope I was of help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a screen scraper program. Here is an example.
http://download.cnet.com/Screen-Scraper-Basic-Edition/3000-2381_4-10513301.html

Comment: I am going to try this also.